# AOP interception, Is it possible maintain the track of my exception with pre and pos functions call list

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, aop, spring-aop, interceptor

I am working on WCF and want to implement some functionality like

i: When an exception occur in any piece of code, I want to list all function call before this exception and also after this exception (those who don't run due to exception)
ii: I implement interception on function but at before and after built In functions there is no complete information regarding to trace complete function call of a user.

For Example 
If I have 5 function like a,b,c,d and e
when exception occur at c function, we need complete information(function names, parameters list ect) of pre functions (a and b) and post functions(d and e).
Note: functions can be nested.

```
 public class ParameterValidator : IParameterInspector
{
    public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
    {
        PostAcitivity(ActivityUtil.PopulateBeforeCallActivity(operationName, inputs)).Wait();
        return null;
    }

    public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
    {
        //PostAcitivity(ActivityUtil.PopulateAfterCallActivity(operationName, outputs, returnValue, correlationState)).Wait();
    }
```

}

Comment: @Zeina, i have acheived the method interception, i get the name of Method which invoked. I want to keep the track of method called like c, want to know about previous methods which got hits.

Comment: @Zeina ,parameterzied intercepts
in c#

Comment: @azeemdaulat can you please us some demo code that you have done? and what you have achieved through it?

and read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Zeina please check the code that i have use for interception